# scrapy uses parse() as its callback function,But I cannot find the place where calls it

Tags: parsing, scrapy

> Scrapy creates scrapy.http.Request objects for each URL in the
>   start_urls attribute of the Spider, **and assigns them the parse method
>   of the spider as their callback function**.

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spider.py

The documents has the description as above. But I cannot find the place where calls **parse()** as its callback function.

`def parse(self, response):
    raise NotImplementedError`

Can someone let me know where calls the function above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in [`scrapy/core/scraper.py`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L138):

```
def call_spider(self, result, request, spider):
    result.request = request
    dfd = defer_result(result)
    dfd.addCallbacks(request.callback or spider.parse, request.errback)
    return dfd.addCallback(iterate_spider_output)
```